# NTP timestamps using std::chrono

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, ntp

I'm trying to represent [NTP timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Timestamps) (including the NTP epoch) in C++ using `std::chrono`. Therefore, I decided to use a 64-bit unsigned int (`unsigned long long`) for the ticks and divide it such that the lowest 28-bit represent the fraction of a second (accepting trunction of 4 bits in comparison to the original standard timestamps), the next 32-bit represent the seconds of an epoch and the highest 4-bit represent the epoch. This means that every tick takes `1 / (2^28 - 1)` seconds.

I now have the following simple implementation:

```C
#include <chrono>

/**
 * Implements a custom C++11 clock starting at 1 Jan 1900 UTC with a tick duration of 2^(-28) seconds.
 */
class NTPClock
{

public:

    static constexpr bool is_steady = false;
    static constexpr unsigned int era_bits = 4;                                     // epoch uses 4 bits
    static constexpr unsigned int fractional_bits = 32-era_bits;                    // fraction uses 28 bits
    static constexpr unsigned int seconds_bits = 32;                                // second uses 32 bits

    using duration = std::chrono::duration<unsigned long long, std::ratio<1, (1<<fractional_bits)-1>>;
    using rep = typename duration::rep;
    using period = typename  duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<NTPClock>;

    /**
     * Return the current time of this. Note that the implementation is based on the assumption
     * that the system clock starts at 1 Jan 1970, which is not defined with C++11 but seems to be a
     * standard in most compilers.
     * 
     * @return The current time as represented by an NTP timestamp
     */
    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        return time_point
        (
            std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch())
                + std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(std::chrono::hours(24*25567))   // 25567 days have passed between 1 Jan 1900 and 1 Jan 1970
        );
    };
}
```

Unfortunately, a simple test reveals this does not work as expected:

```C
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#include <catch2/catch.hpp>
#include "NTPClock.h"

using namespace std::chrono;

TEST_CASE("NTPClock_now")
{
    auto ntp_dur = NTPClock::now().time_since_epoch();
    auto sys_dur = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    std::cout << duration_cast<hours>(ntp_dur) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ntp_dur << std::endl;
    std::cout << duration_cast<hours>(sys_dur) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sys_dur << std::endl;
    REQUIRE(duration_cast<hours>(ntp_dur)-duration_cast<hours>(sys_dur) == hours(24*25567));
}
```

Output:

```
613612h
592974797620267184[1/268435455]s
457599h
16473577714886015[1/10000000]s

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PackageTest.exe is a Catch v2.11.1 host application.
Run with -? for options

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NTPClock_now
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\Repos\...\TestNTPClock.cpp(10)
...............................................................................

D:\Repos\...\TestNTPClock.cpp(18): FAILED:
  REQUIRE( duration_cast<hours>(ntp_dur)-duration_cast<hours>(sys_dur) == hours(24*25567) )
with expansion:
  156013h == 613608h

===============================================================================
test cases: 1 | 1 failed
assertions: 1 | 1 failed
```

I also removed the offset of 25567 days in `NTPClock::now` asserting equality without success. I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tick period: <sup>1</sup>/<sub>268'435'455</sub> is unfortunately both extremely fine and also doesn't lend itself to much of a reduced fraction when your desired conversions are used (i.e. between `system_clock::duration` and `NTPClock::duration`.  This is leading to internal overflow of your `unsigned long long` `NTPClock::rep`.

For example, on Windows the `system_clock` tick period is <sup>1</sup>/<sub>10,000,000</sub> seconds.  The current value of `now()` is around 1.6 x 10<sup>16</sup>.  To convert this to `NTPClock::duration` you have to compute 1.6 x 10<sup>16</sup> times <sup>53,687,091</sup>/<sub>2,000,000</sub>.  The first step in that is the value times the numerator of the conversion factor which is about 8 x 10<sup>23</sup>, which overflows `unsigned long long`.

There's a couple of ways to overcome this overflow, and both involve using at least an intermediate representation with a larger range.  One could use a 128 bit integral type, but I don't believe that is available on Windows, except perhaps by a 3rd party library.  `long double` is another option.  This might look like:

```
static time_point now() noexcept
{
    using imd = std::chrono::duration<long double, period>;
    return time_point
    (
        std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(imd{std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            + std::chrono::hours(24*25567)})
    );
};
```

That is, perform the offset shift with no conversion (`system_clock::duration` units), then convert that to the intermediate representation `imd` which has a `long double` `rep`, and the same `period` as `NTPClock`.  This will use `long double` to compute 1.6 x 10<sup>16</sup> times <sup>53,687,091</sup>/<sub>2,000,000</sub>.  Then finally `duration_cast` that to `NTPClock::duration`.  This final `duration_cast` will end up doing nothing but casting `long double` to `unsigned long long` as the conversion factor is simply <sup>1</sup>/<sub>1</sub>.

Another way to accomplish the same thing is:

```
static time_point now() noexcept
{
    return time_point
    (
        std::chrono::duration_cast<duration>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
            + std::chrono::hours(24*25567)*1.0L)
    );
};
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you can multiply any `duration` by `1`, but with alternate units and the result will have a `rep` with the `common_type` of the two arguments, but otherwise have the same value.  I.e. `std::chrono::hours(24*25567)*1.0L` is a `long double`-based `hours`.  And that `long double` carries through the rest of the computation until the `duration_cast` brings it back to `NTPClock::duration`.

This second way is simpler to write, but code reviewers may not understand the significance of the `*1.0L`, at least until it becomes a more common idiom.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This looks very good. Unfortunately I did not yet get to testing it due to some higher priorities. Will get back next week.

Comment: Ok, I just did a quick test of the first version and it works smoothly. Thanks a lot!